# Where can I find good places to watch stars?

Tags: amateur-observing

Where can I find good places to watch stars near me? I live in Leicestershire, England and am looking for good places to watch the sky nearby.

Comment: Feel free to join us in chat when you get up to 20 points, and our UK users can help you figure out a place near you with good sky conditions as described in Envite's answer here and the duplicate post.

Comment: You might find this link useful: http://www.darkskydiscovery.org.uk/

Answer (score 2):

It would have been better to ask about "which conditions must have a good starsighting place".

It must be:

- Dark
- Far from cities
- Not under main flight paths (this depends on which altitude is the object you want to observe)
- High altitude (or any special place with low cloud formation and low turbulence)
- Far from big water bodies that can cause local humidity